# Calculate sum of vectors in numpy array based on dictionary values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like the following, but much larger:

```
array = np.random.randint(6, size=(5, 4))

array([[4, 3, 0, 2],
   [1, 4, 3, 1],
   [0, 3, 5, 2],
   [1, 0, 5, 3],
   [0, 5, 4, 4]])
```

I also have a dictionary which gives me the vector representation of each value in this array:

```
dict_ = {2:np.array([3.4, 2.6, -1.2]), 0:np.array([0, 0, 0]), 1:np.array([3.9, 2.6, -1.2]), 3:np.array([3.8, 6.6, -1.9]), 4:np.array([5.4, 2.6, -1.2]),5:np.array([6.4, 2.6, -1.2])}
```

I want to calculate the average of the vector representations for each row in the array, but when the value is 0, ignore it when calculating average (dictionary shows it as a 0 vector).

For example, for the first row, it should average [5.4, 2.6, -1.2], [3.8, 6.6, -1.9], and [3.4, 2.6, -1.2], and give [4.2, 3.93, -1.43] as the first row of the output.

I want an output which keeps the same row structure, and has 3 columns (each vector in the dictionary has 3 values).

How can this be done in an efficient way? My actual dictionary has over 100000 entries and array is 100000 by 5000.

Comment: You've designed this so there won't be an efficient way. Why don't you just use one big array?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What do you mean by one big array?

Comment: I mean using a 100000 x 5000 x 3 array

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Would it be possible to convert my array into a 3D array based on the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, it would. But you should probably redesign your approach to avoid the dictionary in the first place. But just do `np.array([[dict_[x] for x in row] for row in array])`. Note, this might be slow. Looping over numpy arrays is slow. It may also require too much memory.

Answer (score 2):

For efficiency I would transform the dict to an array and then use advanced indexing for lookup:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
# create problem
>>> v = np.random.random((100_000, 3))
>>> dict_ = dict(enumerate(v))
>>> arr = np.random.randint(0, 100_000, (100_000, 100))
>>> 
# solve
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lookup = np.array(itemgetter(*range(100_000))(dict_))
>>> lookup[0] = np.nan
>>> result = np.nanmean(lookup[arr], axis=1)
```

Or applied to OP's example:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[4, 3, 0, 2],
...    [1, 4, 3, 1],
...    [0, 3, 5, 2],
...    [1, 0, 5, 3],
...    [0, 5, 4, 4]])
>>> dict_ = {2:np.array([3.4, 2.6, -1.2]), 0:np.array([0, 0, 0]), 1:np.array([3.9, 2.6, -1.2]), 3:np.array([3.8, 6.6, -1.9]), 4:np.array([5.4, 2.6, -1.2]),5:np.array([6.4, 2.6, -1.2])}
>>> 
>>> lookup = np.array(itemgetter(*range(6))(dict_))
>>> lookup[0] = np.nan
>>> result = np.nanmean(lookup[arr], axis=1)
>>> result
array([[ 4.2       ,  3.93333333, -1.43333333],
       [ 4.25      ,  3.6       , -1.375     ],
       [ 4.53333333,  3.93333333, -1.43333333],
       [ 4.7       ,  3.93333333, -1.43333333],
       [ 5.73333333,  2.6       , -1.2       ]])
```

Timings against @jpp's method:

```
pp:    0.8046 seconds
jpp:  10.3449 seconds
results equal: True
```

Code to produce timings:

```
import numpy as np

# create problem
v = np.random.random((100_000, 3))
dict_ = dict(enumerate(v))
arr = np.random.randint(0, 100_000, (100_000, 100))

# solve
from operator import itemgetter
def f_pp(arr, dict_):
    lookup = np.array(itemgetter(*range(100_000))(dict_))
    lookup[0] = np.nan
    return np.nanmean(lookup[arr], axis=1)

def f_jpp(arr, dict_):
    def averager(x):
        lst = [dict_[i] for i in x if i]
        return np.mean(lst, axis=0) if lst else np.array([0, 0, 0])

    return np.apply_along_axis(averager, -1, arr)


from time import perf_counter
t = perf_counter()
r_pp = f_pp(arr, dict_)
s = perf_counter()
print(f'pp:  {s-t:8.4f} seconds')
t = perf_counter()
r_jpp = f_jpp(arr, dict_)
s = perf_counter()
print(f'jpp: {s-t:8.4f} seconds')
print('results equal:', np.allclose(r_pp, r_jpp))
```

Comment: How does this deal with the case where a row is `[0, 0, 0, 0]`, i.e. `dict_[0] = np.array([0, 0, 0])` is used everywhere?

Comment: @jpp I'd expect it to return `nan`s.

Comment: Thanks for doing the timings :). Converting `dict` to `np.ndarray` is definitely the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution using [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html).

You should test and benchmark to see if performance is adequate for your use case.

```
A = np.random.randint(6, size=(5, 4))

print(A)

[[3 5 2 4]
 [2 4 5 2]
 [0 3 1 1]
 [3 4 4 5]
 [2 5 0 2]]

zeros = {k for k, v in dict_.items() if (v==0).all()}

def averager(x):
    lst = [dict_[i] for i in x if i not in zeros]
    return np.mean(lst, axis=0) if lst else np.array([0, 0, 0])

res = np.apply_along_axis(averager, -1, A)

array([[ 4.75      ,  3.6       , -1.375     ],
       [ 4.65      ,  2.6       , -1.2       ],
       [ 3.86666667,  3.93333333, -1.43333333],
       [ 5.25      ,  3.6       , -1.375     ],
       [ 4.4       ,  2.6       , -1.2       ]])
```

Comment: How can we ignore the 0 vectors when calculating mean?

Comment: @JackArnestad, See update. There are likely to be more efficient methods.